# Java ME - lwuit radio button

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

```
public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase implements ActionListener {
  Resources resources;
 RadioButton Verifi=new RadioButton("Verification") ;
   RadioButton Enroll=new RadioButton("Enrollment");
StateMachineBase cl=new StateMachineBase()
        {};
ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();
static Form fo,f;
public StateMachine(String resFile) {
        super(resFile);
    }
  StateMachine()
    {

try{
    resources = Resources.open("/NEW AADHAR.res");
}
catch(java.io.IOException err)
{ err.printStackTrace(); }
cl.setHomeForm("Welcome");
 //fo = (Form)cl.startApp(resources,null,true);
fo=Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
f=cl.findWelcome(fo);
Verifi=cl.findVerification(f);
Enroll=cl.findEnrollment(f);
bg.add(Enroll);
bg.add(Verifi);
//f.addCommandListener(this);
Verifi.addActionListener(listener);Enroll.addActionListener(listener);
}
  protected  void initVars() {
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}       

ActionListener listener=new ActionListener(){
     protected void onWelcome_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event)
        {
Verifi.addActionListener(listener);
if(Verifi.hasFocus())
    {
    showForm("Login",null);

    }
    else if (Enroll.hasFocus())
    {
    showForm("Authentication",null);

   }
    else
        Dialog.show("INFORMATION","Select","OK","Cancel");

     }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

};
}
```

Comment: ok fine,but i am confuse about my above question

Comment: In your StateMachine class where you initializing the `Enrollment, Verification and bg`?

Comment: public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase implements ActionListener {   
 Resources resources;
       
StateMachineBase cl=new StateMachineBase()
        {};
      RadioButton bgVerification;
      RadioButton bgEnrollment;
      ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();;

Comment: here in statemachine class and above constructor

Comment: But see object not initialized. thats why you getting null exception.

Comment: which object????????????

Comment: fo = (Form)cl.startApp(resources,"/NEW AADHAR.res",true);
     f=cl.findWelcome(fo);
      f.addCommandListener(this);

    bgVerification=cl.findVerification(fo);
    bgEnrollment=cl.findEnrollment(fo);
    bg.add(bgEnrollment);
    bg.add(bgVerification);
this is fine or should i make changes in above code to get form(welcome) radio button reference

Comment: See Update 3 in my answer and use that code.

Answer (score 0):

Give the group name for `RadioButton` on ResourceEdit#GUI(use the same name for each `RadioButton`).  Use following method is return the `RadioButton`. So use this method.

```
public com.sun.lwuit.RadioButton findRadioButton(Container root) {
   return (com.sun.lwuit.RadioButton)findByName("RadioButton", root);
        //root - Pass the RadioButton added Component.
}
```

---

**Update 1:**

Use this code for getting the form from generated class,

```
GeneratedClass genClass = new GeneratedClass() { };
final Form form = (Form) genClass.startApp(resources, null, true);
```

`GeneratedClass` - Use your class.
`resources` - Use your resource edit

pass that form to `findRadioButton(...);`

---

**Update 2:**

you given 2 `RadioButton` called Verification and Enrollment.
So use the following code,

```
 GeneratedClass genClass = new GeneratedClass() { };
 Form form = (Form) genClass.startApp(resources, null, true);
 RadioButton rbVerification = genClass.findVerification(form);
 RadioButton rbEnrollment = genClass.findEnrollment(form);
```

And check the `RadioButton Group` name on ResourceEdit#GUI. And give the same name for both `RadioButton`.

---

**Update 3:**

Call `StateMachine()` in your `mainMidlet.java` class.

```
public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase implements ActionListener {

    Resources resources;
    RadioButton Verification;
    RadioButton Enrollment;

    public StateMachine(String resFile) {
        super(resFile);
    }

    /**
     * this method should be used to initialize variables instead of
     * the constructor/class scope to avoid race conditions
     */
    StateMachine() {
    }

    protected void initVars() {
    }

    /**
     * @param c
     * @param event
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    protected boolean onWelcomeEXIT() {
        boolean val = super.onWelcomeEXIT();
        return val;
    }

    protected void onWelcome_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {

        super.onSampleRB_RadioButtonAction(c, event);
        Verification = (RadioButton) c;  // initialize here
        if (Verification.hasFocus()) {
           showForm("Login",null);
        } else {
           Dialog.show("INFORMATION", "Please select option", "OK", "Cancel");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Bharath.I get your point plz tell me that i have to call findRadioButton() method or findByName() method and in root i have to pass form name on which I have added radio buttons?

Comment: If you want to get the `RadioButton` means use `findRadioButton()` and where you adding the `RadioButton`?

Comment: i have add my radion button on form

Comment: hey Bharath what do you mean by resources in

Comment: in method final Form form = (Form) genClass.startApp(resources, null, true)

Comment: Pass your `Resources` instance. For ex, `Resources resources = Resources.open("/sample.res");`

Comment: i have done this in statemachine class but it gives error  can not find varaible Resources

Comment: plz can you give me small example for radio button works in statemachine class

Comment: when i run lwuit desktop project,it gives   protected boolean onWelcomeOK() {

        if(r2.isSelected())///error null pointer exception
        showForm("Login",null);
        boolean val = super.onWelcomeOK();
        return val;}
 where r2 is radio button and when i press OK button it give error

Comment: actually i don't understand about multiple methods(for e.g for lets say button) declare in statemachinebase class and how to use them

Comment: protected  void initVars() {
try{
      resources = Resources.open("/NEW AADHAR.res");
        }
catch(java.io.IOException err)
{ err.printStackTrace(); }
      Form f=(Form) cl.startApp(resources,null, true);
  f.addCommandListener(this);
 bgVerification=cl.findVerification(f);
bgEnrollment=cl.findEnrollment(f);
}

Comment: i put this (init()) method code in statemachine class but i got null pointer exception at Form f=(Form) cl.startApp(resources,null, true); when i run it.
    protected boolean onWelcomeOK() {
        // If the resource file changes the names of components this call will break notifying you that you should fix the code
      
        if(bgVerification.isSelected())
        showForm("Login",null);
      boolean val = super.onWelcomeOK();
        return val;
 }
this is my OK button code

Comment: Better i feel create the new project in your netbeans and generate the class file from ResourceEdit.

Comment: Hi bharath,can u sort me out i have welcome form and how do i get the reference of this form in statemachine class,b'coz when i use radio buttons(which are place on welcome form), it give null pointer exception

Comment: Already you got the `Form` from statemachine class using `startApp(...);`. Right?

Comment: this is my code:Form fo = (Form)cl.startApp(resources,"/NEW AADHAR.res",true);
Form f= cl.findWelcome(fo);
f.addCommandListener(this);
 bgVerification=cl.findVerification(f);
bgEnrollment=cl.findEnrollment(f);
bg.add(bgVerification);
bg.add(bgEnrollment);
where bg is button group and this is my button code:    protected void onWelcome_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
super.onWelcome_ButtonAction(c, event);
 if(bgVerification.isSelected())//this line give error
                 showForm("Login",null);
  else
 Dialog.show("INFORMATION","Please select option", "OK","Cancel");

Comment: thanks for your reply i used same thing u mentioned but this line in OKbutton code give error null pointer exception---if(bgVerification.isSelected())

Comment: i use statemachine constructor for declaring above radio buttons,i declare bg as buttongroup so this is fine ?bgVerification and bgEnrollment  StateMachine()
    { 
try{
    resources = Resources.open("/NEW AADHAR.res");

}
catch(java.io.IOException err)
{ err.printStackTrace(); }
cl.setHomeForm("Welcome");
        Form fo = (Form)cl.startApp(resources,"/NEW AADHAR.res",true);
//Form f= cl.findWelcome(fo);

  fo.addCommandListener(this);

 bgVerification=(RadioButton)cl.findVerification(fo);
bgEnrollment=cl.findEnrollment(fo);

}

Comment: Why you are calling `super.onWelcome_ButtonAction(c, event);` and use `hasFocus()` instead of `isSelected()`

Comment: actually resourceEdit generate this super.onWelcome_ButtonAction(c,event) automatically when i create button "OK"

Comment: Oh ok. Because I didn't use these functionality. What you get using `hasFocus()`? also use `bg.setSelected(0)`. this is set the default selected index to 0.

Comment: i get same error NullPointerException at-----if(Verification.hasFocus())

Comment: hi bharath,i tried your code but i get same error NullPointerException at-----if(Verification.hasFocus())

Comment: What you called in main midlet class?  `StateMachine()` or `StateMachine(resources)` ?

Comment: StateMachine(resources),but currently i am running my desktop module,not MIDP

Comment: i am using if(Verification.hasFocus()) and when i click nothing happens

Comment: Ok. So you can remove the code from `StateMachine()` constructor and  just initialize `Verification = (RadioButton) c;` before you checking `if(Verification.hasFocus())`

Comment: where i have to initialize Verification

Comment: Look at the coding clearly. see the `onWelcome_ButtonAction(Component c, ...)` method.

Comment: this is my code:::::   protected void onWelcome_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
        // If the resource file changes the names of components this call will break notifying you that you should fix the code
     
     super.onWelcome_VerificationAction(c, event);
      if(Verification.hasFocus())
{   
showForm("Login",null);
}
else if(Enrollment.hasFocus())
  {
    showForm("Authentication",null);
  
  }
else
{
Dialog.show("INFORMATION","Please select option","OK","CANCEL");
}
    }

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.lwuit.Button cannot be cast to com.sun.lwuit.RadioButton i got this error at Verification=(RadioButton) c;

Comment: Its working fine for me. What did you use in ResourceEdit#GUI?

Comment: I dont understand your problem here. Why you cant create own resource for your application? Are you using `RadioButton` on GUI? If you are adding RadioButton and you add the listener for this means `Component` should return `RadioButton` only.

Comment: please elaborate your answer i can't get it.

Comment: Will you create `onWelcome_ButtonAction` listener for `RadioButton`?

Comment: i write Verification.addActionListener(this);

Comment: `onWelcome_ButtonAction` are you using this action event for button or radiobutton?

Comment: hi bharath how can i do Verification.addActionCommand() b'coz lwuit don't have this method i think b'coz of this radio button is not working

Comment: use `Verification.addActionListener(...);`

Comment: should i use Verification.addActionListener(this) in onWelcome_ButtonAction() method?

Comment: No. Have use any `Button` on the same screen?

Comment: yes i use EXIT button and it works fine but i don't write any code for it i just add exit command for this button-----                          public static final int COMMAND_WelcomeEXIT = 4;

    protected boolean onWelcomeEXIT() {
        return false;
    }

    protected void processCommand(ActionEvent ev, Command cmd) {
        switch(cmd.getId()) {
            case COMMAND_WelcomeEXIT:
                if(onWelcomeEXIT()) {
                    ev.consume();
                }
                return;

        }
    }

Comment: this code is generated by resource editor in statemachinebase class

Comment: Then what is `onWelcome_ButtonAction`? where did add the `onWelcome_ButtonAction` event? which `Component` you are using for this event?

Comment: hi bharath i have edit my question and paste the code of statenachine class

Comment: Clearly i understood you dont understand the flow. I asked lot of times, `onWelcome_ButtonAction` is one of the event(from your code). where you add this event? which component you are using? check it in created GUI at ResourceEdit file

Comment: i add this event on radio button

Comment: See my update 3. Here i already described clearly. Dont use your posted code. use update 3 code.

Comment: it give error at Verification=(RadionButton)c;  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.lwuit.Button cannot be cast to com.sun.lwuit.RadioButton

Comment: You said `onWelcome_ButtonAction` event for `RadioButton`. Then how its return as `Button`? check it in `ResourceEdit#GUI#RadioButton#ActionEvent`.

Comment: in statemachinebase class these methods return radiobutton::::::::: public com.sun.lwuit.RadioButton findVerification(Container root) {
        return (com.sun.lwuit.RadioButton)findByName("Verification", root);
    }

    public com.sun.lwuit.RadioButton findEnrollment(Container root) {
        return (com.sun.lwuit.RadioButton)findByName("Enrollment", root);
    }

Comment: If you are adding `onWelcome_ButtonAction` event to `RadioButton` means it should return `Component c` as `RadioButton`. check it in `ResourceEdit` and choose your `GUI` and select the `RadioButton` and select the `Event` tab and then click the `Action Event` button. See what is happening and let me.

Comment: when i choose Action Event i got this method in statemachine class::::::::::::: protected void onWelcome_VerificationAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
        // If the resource file changes the names of components this call will break notifying you that you should fix the code
        super.onWelcome_VerificationAction(c, event);
    
    }

Comment: Ok. So use this code `Verification = (RadioButton) c;  // initialize here
        if (Verification.hasFocus()) {
           showForm("Login",null);
        } else {
           Dialog.show("INFORMATION", "Please select option", "OK", "Cancel");
        }
`